# Restrict Autocomplete search to "India" in Google Places API

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-places-api

I am using the Google Place Autocomplete API to search for cities in India. I used the following code to filter the Autocomplete:

```
    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
            .setCountry("India")
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i("TAG", "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

On running this code, the autocomplete dialog shows a [Can't load search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz6xl.png) error message.

The same code works fine when I set the country as `.setCountry("UK")`. What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternate method for restricting the autocomplete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change from `.setCountry("India")` to `.setCountry("IN")` write the country code not the name of the country...more info [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder#setCountry(java.lang.String))

Comment: From documentation `This should be a ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code (case insensitive). If this is not set, no country filtering will take place.` https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder#setCountry(java.lang.String)